# sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep

Hi I'm trying to change the content of the multiple files in the folder. I encountered sed error while trying to iterate through array where I store names of the files I need to edit. I tried to use the specific element of the array "`${len_1[0]}`" and it worked perfectly.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
len_1=($(find . -name "*.dita"))
len=${#len_1[@]}
echo $len

for ((i=0; i<=len; i++)); do
    apps=$(grep -Po 'appname="\K[^"]+' ${len_1[$i]}) && 
        title=$(grep -Po '<title>\K[^</title>]+' ${len_1[$i]}) && 
            sed -i "s/_[0-9]\+/_$apps.$title/g" ${len_1[$i]} && 
                sed -i "s/id=\"[0-9]\+\"\+/id=\"$apps.$title\"/g" ${len_1[$i]};
    done
```

As stated before

```
apps=$(grep -Po 'appname="\K[^"]+' ${len_1[0]}) && 
    title=$(grep -Po '<title>\K[^</title>]+' ${len_1[0]}) && 
        sed -i "s/_[0-9]\+/_$apps.$title/g" ${len_1[0]} && 
            sed -i "s/id=\"[0-9]\+\"\+/id=\"$apps.$title\"/g" ${len_1[0]};
```

works perfectly.

The error I get is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Use `set -x` in your script and run it. Then look _closely_ at the trace output that mentions the `sed` command. Count the number of `/` on that line and remember that `/` is the default delimiter of the `s` command in `sed`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found the problem with set -x.

Comment: a useful rule of thumb when you want to do something sed-like but you need to do something more "programmerish" as well, is that it's a good idea to consider using perl.  even if only to avoid running into weird quoting and whitespace issues from trying to merge sh and sed code together.

Comment: Did you also find a solution?

Comment: @Kusalananda The problem was that the grep output saved in title variable contains more matches then I expected. I assumed there is only one <title> per file. This results in taking newline and I assume there is my problem. I will try to take the first match only and leave an update.

Comment: @cas thank you for your suggestion

Comment: also, perl has good HTML parsing libraries, that sed doesn't.  you can't reliably parse or even extract data from HTML (or other structured data formats like XML or JSON) with regular expressions alone.  and with your mention of `<title>`, it looks like that's what you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple matches, `grep -o` will produce multiple lines of output. And newlines end `sed` commands:

```
$ echo abcabbcd | grep -o 'ab*'
ab
abb

$ repl=$(echo abcabcd | grep -o 'ab*')
$ sed -e "s/foo/$repl/"
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Also, `[^</title>]+` means "one or more characters that are not any of `^`, `<`, `/`,  `t`, `i`, `l`, `e`, or `>`". It's probably not what you actually want:

```
$ echo '<title>abcdefgh</title>' | grep -Po '<title>\K[^</title>]+'
abcd
```

You could use the equivalent when the separator is just one character, e.g. `"[^"]*"` is ok. But here something like `<title>\K.*?(?=</title>)'` might work better:

```
$ echo '<title>abcdefgh</title> <title>foobar</title>' | grep -Po '<title>\K.*?(?=</title>)'
abcdefgh
foobar
```

(Though I would avoid tricks like `\K` and lookaheads, and use the simpler `perl -lne 'print $1 if m,<title>(.*?)</title>,'` or post-process the output instead, but that's my preference.)

Comment: You saved me a lot of trouble with your clarification. Thank you.